# wso2 carbon 4.0 clustering instructions

Tags: wso2

Are the instructions at this [link](http://wso2.org/library/articles/introduction-wso2-carbon-clustering) applicable for setting up clustering on carbon version 4.0?  The article is quite old (2009) and carbon has had a major release since then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a significant change in the deployment model in Carbon 4.0.0. This [blog post](http://charithaka.blogspot.com/2012/09/setting-up-minimum-deployment-of-wso2.html) has info to setup a minimum cluster with Carbon 4.0.0 based products.